# Linq to Entities Query is failing to execute

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvvm, linq-to-entities, devforce

I'm trying to create a query object that contains information from 3 different entities. When the query executes, it tells me an  EntityServerException was unhandled. I'm using a DTO for specific columns to be pulled. Here's my basic DTO:

```
public class LeadRestrictionsDto : BasicModelBase
{
    private Guid _userId;
    private Guid _leadId;
    private string _restrictionDescription;
    private DateTime? _modified;

    [Key]
    public Guid UserId
    {
        get { return _userId; }
        set { SetValueAndNotify(() => UserId, ref _userId, value); }
    }

    public Guid LeadId
    {
        get { return _leadId; }
        set { SetValueAndNotify(() => LeadId, ref _leadId, value); }
    }

    public string RestrictionDescription
    {
        get { return _restrictionDescription; }
        set { SetValueAndNotify(() => RestrictionDescription, ref _restrictionDescription, value); }
    }

    public DateTime? Modified
    {
        get { return _modified; }
        set { SetValueAndNotify(() => Modified, ref _modified, value); }
    }
}
```

And here is the query I am trying to write that accepts a guid for a parameter type:

```
  public List<LeadRestrictionsDto> GetLeadRestrictionListingNow(Guid id)
  {

      IEnumerable<LeadRestrictionsDto> restrictions = from user in Manager.Users
                         join lead in Manager.Leads on user.UserId equals lead.OriginalOwnerId
                         join restriction in Manager.UserRestrictionListings on user.UserId equals restriction.UserId
                         where user.UserId == id
                         select new LeadRestrictionsDto
                                    {
                                        Modified = restriction.Modified,
                                        RestrictionDescription = restriction.Description,
                                        UserId = user.UserId,
                                        LeadId = lead.LeadId
                                    };

      List<LeadRestrictionsDto> userRestiction = restrictions.ToList(); //Exception occurs here
      return userRestiction;
  }
```

Here is the exact exception I get:

```
Unable to locate type: System.Linq.IQueryable`1[[Prime.Library.Repository.LeadRestrictionsDto, Prime.Library, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089. Check that the assembly holding this type is available in the bin/exe folder. Also check that both your assemblies and DevForce assemblies have the expected version number on both client and server.
```

It almost seems as if it's trying to find my Dto in my model.edmx? Sorry if that sounds ignorant. Does anyone have an idea why I'm getting this exception? I have played with this query in LINQPad and it pulls data back with no issues.

Comment: Can you give some details on the structure and types of the involved projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it had something to do with our server not being updated, but I was able to get around it with returning an anonymous type like so:

```
  public List<LeadRestrictionsDto> GetLeadRestrictionListingNow(Guid id)
  {

      var restrictions = from user in Manager.Users
                         join lead in Manager.Leads on user.UserId equals lead.OriginalOwnerId
                         join restriction in Manager.UserRestrictionListings on user.UserId equals restriction.UserId
                         where user.UserId == id && (restriction.RestrictionId == 100 || restriction.RestrictionId == 200) && restriction.Active == true
                         select new 
                                    {
                                        Modified = restriction.Modified,
                                        RestrictionDescription = restriction.Description,
                                        UserId = user.UserId,
                                        LeadId = lead.LeadId,
                                        FirstName = lead.FirstName,
                                        Created = lead.Created,
                                        LastName = lead.LastName

                                    };


      return restrictions.ToList().Select(x=>new LeadRestrictionsDto()
                                        {
                                            Modified = x.Modified,
                                            RestrictionDescription =  x.RestrictionDescription,
                                            UserId = x.UserId,
                                            LeadId = x.LeadId,
                                            FirstName = x.FirstName,
                                            Created = x.Created,
                                            LastName = x.LastName
                                        }).ToList();


  }
```